# Database is in Transistion - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-administration

When someone from my team tried to take a Database offline,  due to a blocking session  the database went into transition state. The session is still present and Now I want to know what is the blocking session running while trying to keep database offline before killing it.

If i try with any dmvs or DBCC Input Buffer i'm getting the same error: Database is in Transition.

Please help me how to find what was the session running.

P.S It is a SQL 2005 database

Comment: What is SP level of database, did you found out what is blocking the database. Run sp_who2 or select * from sys.sysprocesses to see blocking. Close all SSMS connection. You might need to kill all connections blocking the database to go offline. Also there is no need to take DB offline when number of blocks increased

Comment: This would be better directed to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: When i do DBCC INPUTBUFFER(blockin spid id) it errors out -- Database is in transisition. In sp_who2 i'm not able to get what it is exactly doing.